Is there a definition for self intersecting curve?
When studying to math teacher, I met the term self intersecting curve. I was wondering how one could define it rigorously? I saw that algebraic curves might be self intersecting ( What is a self-intersection of an algebraic curve?) but is there a definition for a non-algebraic curve to be self-intersecting?

Depends on what you mean by "non-algebraic curve". One option is defining a curve in a space $X$ as a continuous map $\gamma : I \to X$, where $I \subseteq \mathbf R$ is an interval. A self-intersection can then be defined as a pair $t,t' \in I$ such that $t \neq t'$ and $\gamma(t) = \gamma(t')$. A self-intersecting curve is a curve that is not injective as a map.
